# imagemagick convert -contrast-stretch doesn't work after update to 6.9.x and up

Tags: imagemagick-convert, image-size

I use convert to process my scans. I use convert as follows:

```
convert in.tiff +dither -colors 2 -colorspace gray -contrast-stretch 0 out.tiff
```

The input file is about 8.5MBytes. In V6.8.9-9 the output size is about 1.1MBytes. In 7.0.8-14 the output size stays at 8.5MBytes.

I have searched for problems with `-contrast-stretch`but I couldn't find info on my topic. The same problem occurs with the `-threshold` option. With the old version size gets smaller with the new version size doesn't decrease.

This is on ubuntu 18.04 libtiff-tools is installed. Old Version is on ubuntu 16.04.

Am I missing something?

Regards
  Thommy

Comment: Imagemagick V7 uses magick not convert so I would expect an error. But it may be outputting the original image without any processing?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried with magick but the problem is the same. Size doesn't reduce. I did a diff on in- and output. There are differences, so I assume some processing happened.

Comment: V7 is stricter on the operator order so I would try reducing your code and building it up again. You might find putting the operators in a different order my work.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried: `convert in.tif -threshold 80% -verbose out.tif`. Old Version output size is 1.116MB with new version size is 8.49635MiB. According to `-verbose` output. So I assume the operator order is not the problem. W/o `-verbose`I get the same results in size.

Comment: In general, you should do -contrast-stretch, then -colorspace gray before converting to 2 colors.

Comment: The command line is form [link](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/2colorthresh/index.php) `2colorthresh` script. And it worked so I didn't bother about options order.

Comment: That is my script. In review, I see that what I was doing was converting to two colors, converting those to grayscale, then making sure that they were stretched to full black and white. So that command is OK. But IM 7 is more strict about syntax and there have been other changes so your adding -depth 1 is fine to ensure that the output is bilevel and not truecolor. You probably could have alternately use -type bilevel rather than -depth 1.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I think I tried -type bilevel on my journey but it didn't work. Well I learned a lot about image conversion on my way and now have latest IM installed :-). Also I made my first steps in stackoverflow. And thank you for looking into my subject.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. With `identify -verbose out.tif` I saw that *depth* differed. With the new version it is *8/1-bit* in the old version it is *1-bit*. Searching on that topic I found that `-depth 1` could be the solution. And indeed adding `-depth 1` to the command line solved my problem.

Still I don't know why the old version worked w/o it. But I am back to what I want.

Thommy